remmina-gnome: stuck, buttons not doing anything
I use LinuxMint Wilma.
Installed remmina 1.4.35 via apt.
When I open remmina-gnome, I have:

When I click on buttons, nothing happens. If I add an hotsname, nothing change.
G_MESSAGES_PREFIXED=all G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all remmina-gnome 
(process:766370): remmina-DEBUG: 17:34:44.035: (remmina_file_manager_init) - Initialized the "/home/stardust/.local/share/remmina" data folder
(process:766370): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 17:34:44.038: Using cross-namespace EXTERNAL authentication (this will deadlock if server is GDBus < 2.73.3)
(process:766370): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 17:34:44.042: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ?gio-vfs?
(process:766370): remmina-DEBUG: 17:34:44.053: (remmina_plugin_entry) - gfx_h264_available: 0
(process:766370): remmina-DEBUG: 17:34:44.054: (remmina_rdp_settings_kbd_init) - rdp_keyboard_remapping_list: (null)
(process:766370): remmina-DEBUG: 17:34:44.057: (remmina_plugin_manager_register_plugin) - Remmina plugin glibsecret (type=Secret) has been registered, but is not yet initialized/activated. The initialization order is 2000.
(process:766370): remmina-DEBUG: 17:34:44.120: (remmina_plugin_manager_load_plugins) - The glibsecret secret plugin has been initialized and it will be your default secret plugin
(process:766370): GLib-DEBUG: 17:34:44.120: unsetenv() is not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): GLib-DEBUG: 17:34:44.139: unsetenv() is not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): Gtk-DEBUG: 17:34:44.139: Connecting to session manager
(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): Gtk-DEBUG: 17:34:44.139: Failed to get the GNOME session proxy: The name org.gnome.SessionManager is not owned
(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): remmina-INFO: 17:34:44.202: StatusNotifier/Appindicator support in “xfce xfce”: your desktop does support it
(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): remmina-INFO: 17:34:44.202: StatusNotifier/Appindicator support in “xfce xfce”: and Remmina has built-in (compiled) support for libappindicator.

(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:44.413: gtk_menu_attach_to_widget(): menu already attached to GtkMenuItem
(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): remmina-DEBUG: 17:34:44.418: (remmina_main_init) - Initializing the Remmina main window
(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): remmina-DEBUG: 17:34:44.476: (remmina_main_init) - Initializing monitor
(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 17:34:44.476: Failed to initialize portal (GNetworkMonitorPortal) for gio-network-monitor: Not using portals
(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 17:34:44.477: Using cross-namespace EXTERNAL authentication (this will deadlock if server is GDBus < 2.73.3)
(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 17:34:44.481: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation networkmanager (GNetworkMonitorNM) for ‘gio-network-monitor’
(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): remmina-DEBUG: 17:34:44.484: (remmina_network_monitor_status) - G_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY_FULL
(org.remmina.Remmina:766370): remmina-DEBUG: 17:34:44.692: (remmina_icon_connection_changed_cb) - Indicator connection changed to: 1

I don't use gnome-keyring. I try to connect in cli by ssh, but it fails with:

But I can ssh without password. Remmina try to use password.

flatpak install remmina
flatpak run org.remmina.Remmina

